# How to copy multiple files using PSCP from Unix to Windows?

Tags: unix, scp

With `PSCP.EXE` I am trying to copy multiple files from Unix server to my Windows local.

I am running the below code:

```
pscp.exe -pw password abc@host:"/batch/a1.btc /batch/a2.TMP /batch/a2.TMP" "C:\Users\Me"
```

But it takes the source to be one file instead of 3 files, thus cannot copy them.

How can I copy multiple files with `PSCP`?

Comment: Copying multiple files with `PSCP` was very slow as compared to `PSFTP`. So better to use `PSFTP`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a while ago you wrote this, but I had the same problem. If the files have same endings, same filetype you could use

```
pscp -pw password abc@host:/batch/*.TMP C:\Users\Me
```

Then it will copy all files with the ending .TMP!

Answer (score 1):

Run them in batch mode like this through a script:

```
pscp.exe -batch -pw password abc@host:/batch/a1.btc C:\Users\Me
pscp.exe -batch -pw password abc@host:/batch/a*.TMP C:\Users\Me
```

Comment: It will login and logout each time, and it will be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

The below command can be used to transfer multiple files using PSCP:

```
pscp.exe -unsafe -scp -pw password "abc@host:/batch/a1.btc /batch/a2.TMP /batch/a2.TMP" "C:\Users\Me"
```